# How to order x axis based on y axis values (in decreasing order)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to make bars in clustered column plot appearing with a decreasing ordered based on values of y axis(pososto).I tryed aes(x=reorder(allele,-pososto,sum(and mean)) but those didn't work.If someone can help it would be perfect.
Thank you in advance!

Part of my data:

```
df <- structure(list(allele = c("Ak24:02", "Ak24:02", "Ak24:02", "Ak24:02", 
"Ak02:01", "Ak02:01", "Ak02:01", "Ak02:01", "Ak01:01", "Ak01:01", 
"Ak01:01", "Ak01:01", "Ak11:01", "Ak11:01", "Ak11:01", "Ak11:01", 
"Ak03:01", "Ak03:01", "Ak03:01", "Ak03:01", "Ak32:01", "Ak32:01", 
"Ak32:01", "Ak32:01", "Ak26:01", "Ak26:01"), subject = c("her", 
"reth", "las", "xan", "her", "reth", "las", "xan", "her", "reth", 
"las", "xan", "her", "reth", "las", "xan", "her", "reth", "las", 
"xan", "her", "reth", "las", "xan", "her", "reth"), pososto = c(6.2076749, 
0, 14.3529412, 0, -0.7751938, 0, -0.7751938, 0, 5.0666604, 0, 
0, 11.944798, 0, 0, 9.7559913, 6.0631187, -12.4022258, -1.3476446, 
13.1983584, 17.1626014, 0, -13.1511297, 14.7583726, -5.6592186, 
0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26"
))
```

My basic code:

```
    df = data.frame(allele, subject, pososto)
  df$subject <- factor(df$subject, levels =c("her", "xan", "las", "reth"))
  df$pososto = as.numeric(df$pososto)
  p=ggplot(df, aes(x = allele, y = pososto, fill = subject)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "identity", aes(fill= subject)) +
    #gia labels
    # geom_text(aes(label = round(count, 2)),position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
    #             vjust = ifelse(df[,3]>=0, -0.5, 1) , size= 3)+
    scale_x_discrete(limits = (unique(df$allele))) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#696969","#778899","#A9A9A9","#CCCCFF"))+
    theme_bw(base_size = 9) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "black") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))strong text`
```

dataframe is looking like this:

[image]

The plot I am taking from basic code:

[image]

Comment: To help us to help would you mind sharing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: Oh,I am sorry I forgot to upload them.I will edit my quest.Thanks!

Comment: (: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)  (and xkcd.com/2116). To share your data, you could type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET[1:20, ])` for the first twenty rows of data.

Comment: ... this said: The question is how you will reorder your bars? As there are multiple bars with negative and positive values `reorder(..., sum)`will e.g. reorder by the sum over all bars per `allele`.

Comment: Thank you.Is there any way that can make all bars shown in descending order regardless of each allele?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. To order the bars in decreasing order without grouping by `allele` you could add a helper variable via `interaction` which could then be mapped on `x`.

To only show the `allele` on the x axis I make use of a custom labels function in `scale_x_discrete` and use an underscore as separator in interaction.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df$subject <- factor(df$subject, levels =c("her", "xan", "las", "reth"))
df$pososto = as.numeric(df$pososto)

df$x <- interaction(df$allele, df$subject, sep = "_")

ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(x, -pososto), y = pososto, fill = subject)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ gsub("^(.*?)_.*$", "\\1", .x)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#696969","#778899","#A9A9A9","#CCCCFF"))+
  theme_bw(base_size = 9) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "black") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes,It seems what I need.! I tried it but nothing has changed..I don't know if I am doing something wrong..
<code>...
df$subject <- factor(df$subject, levels =c("her", "xan", "las", "reth"))
  df$pososto = as.numeric(df$pososto)
  df$x <- interaction(df$allele, df$subject, sep = "_")
  p=ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(allele,-pososto), y = pososto, fill = subject)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "identity", aes(fill= subject)) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ gsub("^(.*?)_.*$", "\\1", .x)) +...

Comment: @stefan, this looks sound. Though, I am still wondering how one could sort descending `pososto` within each `allelle`. So, basically, having 7 distinct levels if `allelle` ∈ {Ak24, Ak11, ..., Ak32} and sort descending based on `pososto` within each level.

Comment: Hi @Mel. The issue is that you did `aes(x=reorder(allele,-pososto), ...` instead of mapping the helper variable x on the x aes, i.e. do `aes(x=reorder(x,-pososto), ...`.

Comment: Thank you so much!I tryied to order the dataframe based on pososto column with abs values and it worked.I'm gonna try your way too.
(I did: df=df[order(abs(as.numeric(df$pososto)),decreasing = TRUE),] after I created the dataframe,if someone needs this)

Comment: @Dion. Have a look at the answer by TarJae. There are as always different ways to achieve this result. But the most simple in my opinion is indeed to rearrange the dataset and then fixing the order, where I probably would have made use of `forecast::fct_inorder` but TarJae's approach using `row_number` is also absolutely fine.

Comment: @stefan Thanks for notifying me and you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for such a solution?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  arrange(allele, pososto, subject) %>% 
  group_by(allele) %>% 
  mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  mutate(subject = fct_reorder(allele, id)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = allele, y = pososto, fill=factor(id))) + 
  geom_col(position=position_dodge())+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = (unique(df$allele))) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 9) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#696969","#778899","#A9A9A9","#CCCCFF"), labels = c("her", "reth", "las", "xan"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(allele = c("Ak24:02", "Ak24:02", "Ak24:02", "Ak24:02", 
"Ak02:01", "Ak02:01", "Ak02:01", "Ak02:01", "Ak01:01", "Ak01:01", 
"Ak01:01", "Ak01:01", "Ak11:01", "Ak11:01", "Ak11:01", "Ak11:01", 
"Ak03:01", "Ak03:01", "Ak03:01", "Ak03:01", "Ak32:01", "Ak32:01", 
"Ak32:01", "Ak32:01"), subject = c("her", "reth", "las", "xan", 
"her", "reth", "las", "xan", "her", "reth", "las", "xan", "her", 
"reth", "las", "xan", "her", "reth", "las", "xan", "her", "reth", 
"las", "xan"), pososto = c(6.2076749, 0, 14.3529412, 0, -0.7751938, 
0, -0.7751938, 0, 5.0666604, 0, 0, 11.944798, 0, 0, 9.7559913, 
6.0631187, -12.4022258, -1.3476446, 13.1983584, 17.1626014, 0, 
-13.1511297, 14.7583726, -5.6592186)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"
))
```

[image]